# Path Finder code, __getitem__ TypeError

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror

I am trying to make a "path finder"

```
def find_all_paths(start, end, graph, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return [path]
    paths = []
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path)
            for newpath in newpaths:
                paths.append(newpath)
    return paths


 graph={1: ['2'], 2: ['3', '4', '5'], 3: ['4'], 4: ['5', '6'], 5: [], 6: []}
```

if I enter `find_all_paths(2,5,graph)` in the shell I should get back all the paths that go from key 2 in the graph dictionary to the the 5 values
a proper result should be something like

```
path=[[2,5],[2,3,4,5][2,4,5]]
```

the code keeps giving values errors such as

```
   for node in graph[start]:
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

could someone please help me get this thing running

Comment: You should avoid initialising a parameter with a mutable value like a `list`. See [Common Gotchas](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments) in the The Hitchhiker’s Guide to Python!

Comment: use `print()` to check what you have in `graph` - it seems you assign single number instead of list or directory.

Comment: The recursive call is wrong: the passed arguments don't respect the parameters. Replace by this: `newpaths = find_all_paths(node, end, graph, path)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several awkwardness and errors:

Instead of initialising the *path* parameter with a list, use `None`.
And create the empty list in the function body.

```
def find_all_paths(start, end, graph, path=None):
    path = path or []
```

The values passed to the `find_all_paths` doesn't respect the signature.
Write this instead:

```
newpaths = find_all_paths(node, end, graph, path)
```

Since the values are integer, the graph must contain `int` instead of `strings`.

```
graph = {1: [2], 2: [3, 4, 5], 3: [4], 4: [5, 6], 5: [], 6: []}
```

Here is the fixed version of your code:

```
def find_all_paths(start, end, graph, path=None):
    path = path or []
    path.append(start)
    if start == end:
        return [path]
    paths = []
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpaths = find_all_paths(node, end, graph, path)
            for newpath in newpaths:
                paths.append(newpath)
    return paths
```

If you try this:

```
graph = {1: [2], 2: [3, 4, 5], 3: [4], 4: [5, 6], 5: [], 6: []}
print(find_all_paths(2, 5, graph))
```

You'll get:

```
[[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: The use of `path.append(start)` in place of `path = path + [start]` breaks the algorithm, unfortunately, since it modifies the caller's copy of the path.  If this change is reverted, it will match the poster's "correct" answer (`[[2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 5], [2, 5]]`).

Comment: great code no doubt, but not the path I am looking for as I stated earlier I want it to be something like path=[[2,5],[2,3,4,5][2,4,5]]
it is supposed to show every available path
yours showed [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]] but 6 is not related tot he group

Comment: @Enigma All right, It's up to you to implement the right algorithm…